# generate JSON file content

Tags: python, json, generate

I am a beginner with JSON.

I have the following in my JSON file (file-1) :

```
{
    "Aps": [
      {
            "type": "opo",
            "price_min": 7,
            "price_max":10,
            "app_time": 0,
           
            "arguments": {
                "prices": 15,
                "apps_num": "112"
            },
            "attributes": {
            "name":"user1",
            "priority":"100"
            
            } 
    }
}
```

How write python code that generates another JSON file that contain the same content of file-1 but duplicated 100 time in each time the name of user is different user2, user3 ... user100 and also it's priority.

I have tried the following but it is not working :

```
for lp in range(100):
    with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)
```

but it is not working ..

the required output is as follow :

```
{
    "Aps": [
      {
            "type": "opo",
            "price_min": 7,
            "price_max":10,
            "app_time": 0,
           
            "arguments": {
                "prices": 15,
                "apps_num": "112"
            },
            "attributes": {
            "name":"user1",
            "priority":"100"
            
            } 
    }, 
      {
            "type": "opo",
            "price_min": 7,
            "price_max":10,
            "app_time": 0,
           
            "arguments": {
                "prices": 15,
                "apps_num": "112"
            },
            "attributes": {
            "name":"user2",
            "priority":"90"
            
            } 
    },
   {
            "type": "opo",
            "price_min": 7,
            "price_max":10,
            "app_time": 0,
           
            "arguments": {
                "prices": 15,
                "apps_num": "112"
            },
            "attributes": {
            "name":"user2",
            "priority":"80"
            
            } 
    },
..............

}
```

Comment: So you want to add to the "Aps" value other 99 dictionaries where the "name" value grows up to 100 and the "priority"'s decrease to -900?

Comment: whatever the value is, the most important is how to duplicate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a little code here using json and copy module

json for reading and writing json files

copy because I had some trouble with reference variables see [documentation for copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html); if I changed 'temp' dict then it would affect all occurrences in 'file' dict

```
import json
import copy

repeats = 100
file = json.loads(open('file.json', 'r').read())
temp1 = json.loads(open('file.json', 'r').read())['Aps'][0]
for repeat in range(repeats):
    temp = copy.deepcopy(temp1)
    temp['attributes']['name'] = f"user{repeat + 2}"
    temp['attributes']['priority'] = f"{repeat*10+100 - repeat*20}"
    file['Aps'].append(temp)
    temp1 = copy.deepcopy(temp)
json.dump(file, open('file1.json', 'w'), indent=4)
```

Comment: your answer is AWSOME .. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert your json file to a python object (dict):

```
import json

file = open('sample.json')
data = json.load(file)
file.close()
```

Now you can do stuff with your `Aps` list, like appending the first object 100 times to your list.

```
for dups in range(100):
    data['Aps'].append(data['Aps'][0])
```

Then you save your dict to a json file again:

```
with open("sample.json", "w") as outputfile:
    json.dump(data, outputfile)
```